# How do I make a generated Object name?

Tags: c#, object

How do I make a generated Object name? For example:

```
ObjectEx "name" = new ObjectEx();
```

**Edit:**

The object will be named by a user input.
The code will be:

```
Console.Write("Input new user's name: ");
string newUsersName = Console.ReadLine();
(Create ObjectEx)
```

**Edit2:**

I have a `Dictionary` for `ObjectEx`(`Person`) which handles all `ObjectEx`s.

`Person` is the real class name, sorry about making the example object `ObjectEx`.

```
public static List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();
```

Comment: And how will you use it then?

Comment: Why would you want to? The compiler doesn't care too much for your pretty names

Comment: Objects don't have names. Stop and think this through.

Comment: Following your edit. The variables name doesn't change just its value

Comment: Is there a way i could create a new object with a string name?

Comment: That's what I'm asking..

Comment: `class ObjectEx { public String Name; }`

Comment: What everyone else is saying is the variable name is irrelevant, just its value

Comment: Revised, but .. `List` is not `Dictionary`.

Answer (score 6):

Objects don't have names - variables do, and they're always determined at compile-time.

If you want a map from string to object, just use a `Dictionary<string, ObjectEx>` - then come with random strings using `Random`. (There are plenty of examples of generating random strings on Stack Overflow.)

If you just want a collection of objects and you were using "random name" as a way of expressing that, use `List<ObjectEx>` - you don't need a name at all in that case.

If you need something else, please be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array` and store object in to that.

```
ObjectEx []arrObjectEx  = new ObjectEx[10];
arrObjectEx[0]   = new ObjectEx();
```

I would use [`list<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) (generic list) instead of array if the number of random elements are unknown.

```
List<ObjectEx> lstObjectEx = new List<ObjectEx>();
lstObjectEx.Add(new ObjectEx());
```

If randomly generated object need to be accessed uniquely then you can use [dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx). e.g

```
Dictionary<int, ObjectEx> dicObjectEx = new Dictionary<int, ObjectEx>();
dicObjectEx.Add(someUniqueNumber, new ObjectEx());
```

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible but how about using a [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). You can use a string value Add and Get hold of an Object you stored.

```
// somewhere near the start in your code initialize the dictionary 
var dict = new Dictionary<string, Person>();

// later on you can dynamically add an Object to the Dictionary
// newUsersName is the so called Index
string newUsersName = Console.ReadLine();
dict.Add(newUsersName, new Person());

// if you need to get hold of that object again use the Index
// myObj is a Person type
var myObj = dict[newUsersName];
// assume Person has an Age property 
myObj.Age = 20;


// show all Persons now in the dictionary
foreach(var username in dict.Keys)
{
    Console.WriteLine(username);
    var pers = dict[username];
    Console.WriteLine("{0} is {1} years old", username, pers.Age ); 
}
```

Comment: How do i change the dict to a Dictionary?

Comment: `dict` already is of type `Dictionary`, why do want to change it?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dictionary to store objects, where the Key is the object name